# How to generate two keys with the same value in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I'm attempting to generate 2 `azurerm_key_vault_key`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_key

I need both of them to have the same value(to be the same key exactly but in different keyvault). Is it possible to achieve that? I can't find anyway to explicitly define the key's value so I could generate it beforehand. Is that possible to have 2 keys like that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 2 Keys in different Azure Key Vaults with same values.

Unfortunately it is not possible to import Key in Azure Key Vault with terraform, but you can use REST call to import Key into Azure Key Vault.
You can generate Keys beforehand and import it into both Azure KeyVaults.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/importkey/importkey

I created Key Import feature request in Azure Terraform provider, please vote.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10301